# Cannot use any method in Picasso library

Tags: android, dependencies, picasso

So I have added this dependency in my Android project:

```
implementation ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: ['exifinterface', 'support-annotations']
}
```

I am unable to call any method in Picasso. All I can see after putting a `.` (dot) after `Picasso` in my code are these

[image]

However, I then created a fresh new Android project and then tried to use Picasso, and it worked. I don't know what is the issue with the current one. Also, kindly mention in the comments if I need to provide more information regarding my project, such as my `build.gradle` file.

Thanks!

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Not working sadly.

Comment: I was doing a silly mistake, I will be more careful before posting on SOF.

Answer (score 0):

If clean, rebuild or Invalidate cashes and restart do not help you, you can use Glide library. Find about Glide in attached link:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: The worse thing is that I am having pretty similar issues with Glide too.

Comment: Try to change your support:appcompat version to this in you app gradle file:
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0

Comment: And try to use only this line in gradle:
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso3:picasso:2.71828'  ---- without {} this braces

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a silly mistake. I was trying to call the Picasso methods inside my Activity class, but outside all the methods of the class. I then called the methods inside my `onCreate()` method. I hope this answer helps someone who is doing the same mistake.